Can Kleptothermy work underwater?
I am working on a concept with amphibian larvae surviving in very cold polar waters. Kleptothermy seems to work with ectothermic organisms (like Snakes and Bees) but I can't find any organism that does this underwater. Is there a reason why this doesen't occur in aquatic animals? Is there something about water that makes heat transfer around organisms difficult?

Yes, kleptothermy can work underwater. Marine animals like sea turtles and fish use it to share body heat in cold waters. This strategy helps them maintain their body temperature, reducing energy expenditure and enhancing survival in the thermally challenging aquatic environment.

Can I get a source for that? I tried to google these and found nothing indicating they can.
